# conversion from 'const wchar_t' to 'std::ctype<char>::_Elem', possible loss of data

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I get this warning during compile though the program seems to be working properly. Is it something I can ignore? How do I get rid of it?

This is my code.

```
string toNarrow(const wstring& str)
{
    ostringstream stm ;
    const ctype<char>& ctfacet = 
                         use_facet< ctype<char> >( stm.getloc() ) ;
    for( size_t i=0 ; i<str.size() ; ++i ) 
                  stm << ctfacet.narrow( str[i], 0 ) ;
    return stm.str() ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using `ctype<wchar_t>` rather than `ctype<char>`

Comment: Sorry, the markdown was not rendering the template parameters. I think it should be fixed.